# smcaps.sty file not found

Tags: compiling

New to TeX. Using TeXnicCenter with MiKTeX. Attempting to compile an existing `.tex` file and get the error LaTeX error: File `smcaps.sty` not found.

Is this file part of an uninstalled package? I thought MiKTeX installed missing packages on the fly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found `smcaps.sty` in an quite old version of [`README`](http://www.sissa.it/download/online-manuals/tex/teTeX/fonts/cmbright/README) of [`cmbright`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmbright):

> (4) Help! CM Bright does not provide 'small capitals'.
>
> Company names, acronyms, trade marks and similar material    may be
>   typeset capitalized.  In order to make the result    less obtrusive,
>   the font size should be one 'step'    smaller than the surrounding
>   text.  A 'quick and dirty'    way to make LaTeX perform this task is
>   the following    style file `smcaps.sty`.  It defines the new command 
>   `\textc{..}`, which may be used in place of `\textsc{..}`:
>
> ```
> \ProvidesPackage{smcaps}
> \DeclareRobustCommand{\sm@ller}{%
>   \dimen@\f@size\p@
>   \ifdim \dimen@ > 12\p@
>     \dimen@=0.83333\dimen@
>   \else
>     \advance \dimen@ -\p@
>   \fi
>   \math@fontsfalse
>   \fontsize{\the\dimen@}\z@
>   \selectfont
>   }
> \newcommand{\textc}[1]{{\sm@ller\uppercase{#1}}}
> % end of smcaps.sty
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Heiko's answer, it sounds like `smcaps.sty` is a very old package that has all but disappeared from distributions, hence MiKTeX is unlikely to be able to install it, on the fly or not.

But you shouldn't be needing it anyway. Small capitals are a property of the font and nor usually available as a separate package.  If the font you're using has them, you can access small capitals with the command `\textsc`.

In order to say anything more useful, we will need to see your actual document.